Connect PHP and SQL Server using Visual Studio Code. using localhost and xampp as well
Where should I place my PHP file? It's currently in a project folder.
I have downloaded the Microsoft SQL Server extension in VSCode but still the undefined problem of couldn't connect the database for running the website.
I've even followed the step from YouTube but still there's some errors that I may make careless but I can't find it.

<?php

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $database = "WeighingDB";
    $uid = "sa";
    $pass = "1234567890";

    $connectionOptions = [
        "Database" => $database,
        "UID" => $uid,
        "PWD" => $pass
    ];

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionOptions);
    if($conn == false) 
        //die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        echo 'failed';
    else
        echo 'Connected Successfully';
        

?>


I am seeking clear steps guiding me of connecting the PHP to the SQL Server and my other web program (HTML, CSS, JS).

Have you installed a version of Microsoft SQL Server somewhere? The SQL Server extension for VS Code is just an extension to connect to and query existing databases, it doesn't host any itself.

You would need to list the steps you followed from the YouTube video.

I am assuming that:

PHP is installed and correctly configured.
SQL Server is installed and running.
SQLSRV extension for PHP installed.

You can download the SQLSRV extension from the MS Drivers for PHP for SQL SERVER
After downloading, extract the folder and copy the php_sqlsrv.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll files to your PHP extensions directory (usually named ext).
Open your php.ini file and add the following lines to enable the extension
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll

After changes in your php.ini file you need to restart your webserver.
To verify that the extension is loaded properly create a PHP file like phpinfo.php and add the following code in it.
<?php
phpinfo();
?>


Access this file in your browser (e.g., http://localhost/your_project/phpinfo.php). This will display the PHP configuration page where you can confirm that the SQLSRV extension is listed.
Here is the modified version of your script to handle errors properly and to ensure the connection string is correct
<?php

$serverName = "localhost";
$database = "WeighingDB";
$uid = "sa";
$pass = "1234567890";

$connectionOptions = [
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $uid,
    "PWD" => $pass,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
];

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    echo 'Connected Successfully';
}
?>



In your browser access your PHP file like (http://localhost/your_project/phpinfo.php). If everything is configured correctly, you should see "Connected Successfully".
